# Unsigned Long Long out of range?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, 64-bit, long-integer

Ok, this is a weird issue :

- I'm using `unsigned long long` variables (I've used even `long` ones, with the same effect)
- I *need* to be able to store 64-bit integers (`sizeof` returns 8, which is fine)

However, when I'm trying to go to values like `1<<63`, and perform some simple bitwise operations, I - oddly - seem to be getting negative values. Why's that?

**My test code :**

```
    unsigned long long c = 0;

    c |= 1l << 56; printf("c = %lld\n",c);
    c |= 1l << 63; printf("c = %lld\n",c);
```

**Output :**

```
c = 72057594037927936 
c = -9151314442816847872
```

---

***Sidenotes :***

1. Of course, same thing happens even if I do `c = 1l<<63` directly.
2. All tests made on Mac OS X 10.6, and compiled using Apple's LLVM Compiler 3.0

---

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you *need* 64-bit integers, you might prefer to use uint64_t.

Comment: I know you've already selected an answer, but I still have a question: Are you compiling for a 64-bit core?  What is `sizeof(long)`?  I'm surprised that `1l<<63` works, as I'd have thought that it would be shifting a 32-bit `1l` up by 63 bits, leaving you with a value of zero.  But if `sizeof(long)` is also 8, maybe that's why it works.  If I'm correct, then there's some truth to Jesse Rusak's answer, even though that answer wouldn't solve your problem.

Comment: Yeah the `1l` really should be `1ull` to guarantee that it's at least 64 bits long.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `d` part of the `%lld` specifier is telling `printf` that the argument should be treated as a signed integer. Use a `u` instead: `%llu`.

From the man pages:

> **d, i**
>
> > The  int  argument is converted to *signed* decimal notation.
>
> **o, u, x, X**
>
> > The unsigned int argument is converted to  *unsigned*  octal  (o), *unsigned*  decimal  (u),  or *unsigned* hexadecimal (x and X) notation.

Comment: OK, now is one of those times, when after a lot of head-scratching and... multi-level debugging efforts, I feel like an idiot... lol. Guess I've learned something really valuable. (Of course the issue was affecting something a lot bigger... and not just a 2-liner test). Thanks a lot, buddy! You've definitely saved me a lot of time! ;-)

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon: No worries, happens to everyone.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're actually doing something undefined here. I think the expression `1l << 63`  is undefined in C, since the compiler will represent `1l` in a signed type, and shifting by 63 bits causes an signed overflow (which is undefined in C). I'm not an expert, but seems like you want `1ull << 63`.

Your original code, in fact, complains about this if you pass `-Weverything` in clang:

```
foo.c:7:23: warning: signed shift result (0x8000000000000000) sets the sign bit of the
            shift expression's type ('long') and becomes negative [-Wshift-sign-overflow]
      c |= 1l << 63; printf("c = %lld\n",c);
           ~~ ^  ~~
```

EDIT: And, yes, then you need the correct printf format from the other answer.